# docker: 'build' is not a docker command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gcloud

I was following https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart documentation to build the Docker image;

> Run the following Docker command from the directory containing the image's files:

```
docker build -t quickstart-image .
```

But then I get the error message:

```
docker: 'build' is not a docker command.
```

My docker version: `version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

Why is the command not working? Is it because of my docker version?

Comment: You could always execute `which docker` to make sure it is what you expect to be.

Comment: not sure if the docker version is the exact issue, but according to the docker v18 documentation, adding the root directory might solve the issue: `docker build .\ -t quickstart-image .`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still have this problem, but could you verify that there are no hidden characters in your

```
docker build -t quickstart-image .
```

I get this error when I copy-paste from either libre office or word

funny fix for funny problems